# Utility.class (Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software)

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb, build.gradle

I have written the hole source code by myself. We haven't used any library in this class. When i run this android app in release mode then app working fine and in debugging mode it is giving me error

> "Utility.class (Operation did not complete successfully because the
>   file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software)"

. Is there any way to tackle it in android? 
[image: build error]

Comment: as IDE suggested, try to scan and clean virus.

Comment: Did you already look up the error yourself?

Comment: @navylover  how do we do that? I didn't find any option in IDE to clean it.